# When trying to upload a file to Alibaba Cloud OSS using OSS Utility tool it throws access denied

Tags: alibaba-cloud

I am trying to upload a file to Alibaba Cloud OSS using the utility tool. While trying to upload a file to OSS it throws me access denied error, I have full access to the bucket and I tried to find the root cause but am not able to find it, What is missing?, Any suggestions?

Error:
[image]

Comment: What is the bucket ACL? Does this object already exist? The error message is clear that you do not have permission based upon the bucket ACL.

Answer (score 1):

Ranjith. Your screen clearly says: You have no right to access this object because of bucket acl. Please check if you have correct access rights for your user and if not change them.

Answer (score 1):

@Ranjith

Did you try assigning the appropriate RAM roles for accessing the OSS? Also might happen that the AccessKeyId and the AccessKeySecret might be wrong. Please double check and try again.

Comment: Yep, Thanks, The issue with the Access key pairs, I used RAM Access key instead of account...